# Не работает функция play() на мобильных

Tags: javascript

Нужно при загрузке страницы в iframe воспроизводить звуковой файл. На ПК всё работает, на мобильных устройствах (Chrome, Safari) звука нет.

```
<iframe id='page' onload='frameLoaded();' sandbox='allow-same-origin' style="max-width:100px; max-height: 100px;"></iframe>
<button id="btn">GO</button>
```

**Js**:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
   document.getElementById("page").src = "https://wikipedia.org";
}

var mysound = new Audio('sounds/clap.mp3');
frameLoaded = function() {
    mysound.play().then(function() {}).catch(function(error) {alert(error);});
}
```

Ошибка:

```
NotAllowedError: the request is not allowed by the user agent
or the platform in the current context, possible because
the user denied permission.
```

Понятно, что это политика мобильных браузеров, но как-то ведь можно это решить? Воспроизводится же на сайтах звуковой и видео контент.

Comment: На мобильных `play()` срабатывает только от явного действия пользователя, но это можно обойти (по крайней мере раньше можно было). Если не ответят, чуть позже кину пример